# What is the meaning of the quadruple symbols combination on a possibly Roman monumental piece?

Tags: ancient-history, architecture, ancient-rome, symbols, asia-minor

During my visit to a village central western part of the Asia Minor I saw monumental pieces. Which were emplaced on some part of the buildings by villagers. I see a sword, sickle (hook), pickaxe, and an unidentified one on the piece.

What is the small symbol lying on the side of the sword? What is the one below the sword?

I am wondering about what these symbols altogether mean on a single piece and which civilization it belongs to?

Does the [Corinthian style column capital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corinthian_order) of [acanthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acanthus_(plant))(?) leaf, perhaps imply a Roman heritage?

[image: Fig2]
[image]
[image: fig3]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: There are actually several different questions here,  you may get a better answer if you divide them into their own questions.

Comment: The [Corinthian Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corinthian_order) was used in Greek as well as Roman architecture.  Can you be more specific on location? Many different kingdoms and cultures controlled different regions of Asia Minor/Anatolia/Turkey at different times. A specific location might help to narrow this down.

Comment: The location lies on the SW of Afyon Karahisar Province.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top of that column may be quite unrelated to the rest. As we lack more info from the situation and surrounding findings, inferences are also limited for the first two carvings.

But those other two need to be rotated. Then we see a bas reielf for a blacksmith or even locksmith:

[image]

Whether it is from funerary stele or a 'shop sign' seems an open question without further details.

[A site specialising in Roman locksmiths uses a variant of the above image for](https://web.archive.org/web/20180301152326/http://romanlocks.com/Introduction.htm)

> And finally, I'll show that famous image from a locksmith's grave stone, now in the Aquileia museum, that actually shows Roman lock makers at work! Note especially the completed door lock on the lower right. The bellows and tools: hammer, tongs and file, are immediately recognizable, and remain much the same for the next 1500 years and more. Notice also the design oŁ that little furnace, made like a miniature temple.

[Also here:](https://www.anvilfire.com/21centbs/anvils/roman/roman_blacksmith_ill_notes_atli.htm)

> To the right are tongs, hammer, a spearhead and a lock.

The picture I used is credited with:

> Relief depicting a blacksmith's shop and tools (stone), Roman, (3rd century BC) / Museo Nazionale d'Abruzzo, Aquila, Italy / Giraudon / [The Bridgeman Art Library](http://www.bridgemanart.com/en-GB/asset/125456/roman-3rd-century-bc/relief-depicting-a-blacksmith-s-shop-and-tools-stone)